# Dividing by vector after factoring out

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If I factor out a matrix from an equation and then am left with 0 on one side, can I effectively cancel out the vector by dividing both sides by it?

A trivial example being
$$
\begin{align}
AB\hat{x} - AC &= 0 \implies\\
A(B\hat{x} - C) &= 0 \implies\\
B\hat{x} - C &= 0
\end{align}
$$

while also obviously considering that $A=0$ is a possibility or has been assumed to not be $0$

Comment: No, we cannot do this in general. Do an example with $2\times 2$-matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The correct analogy to the usual $xy=0$ implying $x=0$ or $y=0$ over the reals (or really any integral domain) uses *invertibility* of square matrices:

When $A$ is a (real or complex) square matrix and $x$ is a vector, the equation $Ax=0$ implies that $x=0$ or $A$ is not invertible (which allows more than just $A=0$).

Hence, the implication $$Ax=0\ \Longrightarrow\  x=0$$ is only true, when $A$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: Okay, understood - thanks. 
If I instead had, perhaps something like $A[x-A^Tb]=0$ and the dimensions all match up, could I left multiply by $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ to use inverses to cancel out the $A$?

Comment: Assuming that $A^TA$ is invertible, yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the dimensions of the various things, which you do not define but I imagine $A,B,C$ to be square or rectangular matrices and $X$ to be a column vector, your equation does not make sense as it sums matrices of different sizes.

Even if the equation would make sense the answer would be no as you can simplify $A$ only if it is invertible (so you are actually multiplying by $A^{-1}$). In general with matrices you can have $AB=0$ with $A\neq 0$, $B\neq 0$.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't pay too much attention to dimensions as the example was just an abstract one. If the dimensions did match up however, and $(A^TA)$ was square and invertible, would a left multiply by $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ to use inverses to cancel out the $A$ be valid?